# Scapy timestamp Accuracy

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to find latency between 2 interfaces. I am using custom packets using scapy. My idea was to use the sniff function in scapy, to get tx and rx time. However I would like to understand the accuracy of these timestamps.

I researched using strace, and found that the linux sock opts were not set to generate timestamps. Can I use these timestamps for latency measurement ?